# How to create user profile theme hook suggestion for custom template?

Tags: theming, users, nodes, entities

I'm using the Chaos tools display suite module to create a 'mini_teaser' view mode for my user profiles, but I can't seem to get drupal to read a custom template `'user-profile__mini_teaser.tpl.php'` in my theme folder. In my user preprocess function, I'm adding theme suggestions, but they don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code but off the top of my head your preprocess function should look something like this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view_mode'] == 'mini_teaser') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user_profile__mini_teaser';
  }
}
```

Or a more generic solution:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user_profile__' . $vars['view_mode'];
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, but the `$vars['view_mode']` value appears to be located in `$vars['elements']['#view_mode']`. Found by `dpm($vars);` in the preprocess function.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would replace the underscores from

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user_profile__mini_teaser';
```

with hyphens in the template file name:

i.e, rename template file to:

```
user-profile--mini-teaser.tpl.php
```

After clearing theme registry cache, see if that, or a similar underscore / hyphen filename adjustment helps.